# Capturing an invoked function and its argument passed in as an argument

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am new to JavaScript and have several questions about functional programming.

Here is a statement:

```
outer(inner(5));
```

1. Is it possible to construct function `outer` in a way that allows it
   to capture function `inner` and its argument `5`?
2. Is it possible to construct function `inner` in a way that allows it to
   pass itself and its argument `5` to function `outer`?
3. If the answer to both questions above is no, is it possible to
   construct functions `outer` and `inner` in a way that allows the former
   to capture function `inner` and its argument `5` or the
   latter to pass itself and its argument `5` to function
   `outer`?

I tried:

using the `arguments` object but to no avail.

```
function outer (parameter) {
    return arguments;
}

function inner (n) {
    return n + 1;
}

console.log(outer(inner(5))); // returns Arguments { 0: 6 ... }
```

using *currying* but I do not see how it can help me since I am not given the following statement:

```
outer()(5);
```

Comment: The problem in your `outer(inner(5))` statement is that you are not passing a function to a function, you are passing its return value. So what you are really running is `outer(6)` and `6` doesn't have any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround consists in returning an array from `inner()` composed of on one side the processing function and on the other side the argument.
`outer` will be able to access both by reading the array.

```js
function outer(arr)
{
    var fun    = arr[ 0 ];
    var arg    = arr[ 1 ];
    var result = fun(arg);
    console.log('inner function is:', fun);
    console.log('its argument is:', arg);
    console.log('its result is:', result);
    return result;
}

function inner(num)
{
    return [
        function (_num)
        {
            return _num + 1;
        },
        num
    ]
}

console.log(outer(inner(5)));
```

Comment: This solution checks all the marks I needed to be checked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by letting your `inner` return a function (*foo*) which closes over `n`. You can then let *foo* return `n+1`. Then, within your `outer` function, you can invoke *foo* to get its return value:

```js
const outer = f => f();
const inner = n => _ => n+1;

console.log(outer(inner(5)));
```

Alternatively, another possibility would involve changing your `return` value. You could `return` an array from `inner` which contains the original passed through arguments (`...arguments`) and the returned value (`to_return`) and then use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the passed in argument(s) (`n` & `m`) and the returned `result`:

```js
function outer([result, n, m]) {
    console.log("returned from inner: ", result);
    console.log("arguments passed into inner: " + [n, m]);
    return n;
}

function inner(n, m) {
    let to_return = n + 1;
    return [to_return, ...arguments];
}

console.log(outer(inner(5, 2))); // returns 5
```

- Note: I added an `m` argument to demonstrate how you can extend this to multiple arguments

Comment: This solution is similar to @sasensi's but since his is a bit older than yours I accepted it. I appreciate you taking it further and adding extra arguments though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function outer(myFunction, argument) {
    if (typeof myFunction !== "function") {
        return false;
    }
    return myFunction(argument);
}

function inner(n) {
    return n + 1;
}

console.log(outer(inner, 5));
```

Just a simple approach. Don’t execute the `function inner` but pass it as an argument (myFunction). And let the `outer function` execute it with the given argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem with it is that you change the initial statement: outer(inner(5)). I need it to remain as it is and be able to access not the return value but the function and its argument separately. I appreciate your effort though.